# How to subtract a value in a textbox using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made a html page where employees can enter their in and out times using a textbox, and next to it is a row showing if the employee worked for the full day (out time - in time >= 8 hours) or if its a half day etc.

I'm not sure how to get the number of hours worked. I tried this, but didn't work

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inTime = parseInt($("#in-time").val());
  var outTime = parseInt($("#out-time").val());
  var workHours = outTime - inTime;

  if (workHours => 8) {
    $("#value").text('Full Day')
  } else if workHours < 8) {
    $("#value").text('Half Day')
  } else {
    $("#value").text('error')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-custom2">Employee Name</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">In Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">Out Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">Unnamed</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="table-custom2">Test User</td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="in-time" class="input-xsmall"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="out-time" class="input-xsmall" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><span id="value"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis after the `else if`.

Comment: @D.Pardal my bad. Messed it up when i edited it here. Ill fix it now.

Comment: You should use `oninput` instead of `onkeyup`.

Comment: How exactly are they different? I tried changing it to `oninput` now, but the result was the same. Is it better if I use `oninput`?

Comment: `onkeyup` is for detecting when someone releases a key. `oninput` is for detecting when the `<input>` `value` is changed. The keyboard is not the only way to input text into a field (e.g. right click then "paste"). Also, why not use `<input type="number">`?

Comment: @D.Pardal I was actually planning on using 24 hour format in here and was going to change the `parseInt` to `parseFloat` later, but wanted to understand it better with a simple version of it first. I wasn't sure if it'll work if I used number as the input type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typos in `=>` should be `>=` and missing `(` after `else if`:

```
if (workHours >= 8) {
  $("#value").text('Full Day')
} else if (workHours < 8) {
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inTime = parseInt($("#in-time").val());
  var outTime = parseInt($("#out-time").val());
  var workHours = outTime - inTime;

  if (workHours >= 8) {
    $("#value").text('Full Day')
  } else if (workHours < 8) {
    $("#value").text('Half Day');
  } else {
    $("#value").text('error');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-custom2">Employee Name</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">In Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">Out Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">Unnamed</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="table-custom2">Test User</td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="in-time" class="input-xsmall"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="out-time" class="input-xsmall" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><span id="value"></span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. Need to check my syntax more often

Answer (score 1):

You have missing `{` at else if and change to `>=` not `=>`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inTime = parseInt($("#in-time").val());
  var outTime = parseInt($("#out-time").val());
  var workHours = outTime - inTime;

  if (workHours => 8) {
    $("#value").text('Full Day')
  } else if (workHours < 8) {
  $("#value").text('Half Day')
} else 
{
  $("#value").text('error')
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Tutorial</title>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-custom2">Employee Name</th>
      <th class="table-custom2">In Time</th>
      <th class="table-custom2">Out Time</th>
      <th class="table-custom2">Unnamed</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="table-custom2">Test User</td>
      <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="in-time" class="input-xsmall"></td>
      <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="out-time" class="input-xsmall" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
      <td class="table-custom3"><span id="value"></span></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also `>=` not `=>`

Comment: For some reason I keep getting Full Day in the Snippet :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you. I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `onInput` to solve this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inTime = parseInt($("#in-time").val());
  var outTime = parseInt($("#out-time").val());
  var workHours = outTime - inTime;
  console.log(workHours);
  if(workHours >= 8) $('#value').text('Full');
  else if(workHours < 8 && workHours > 0) $('#value').text( 'Half');
  else console.log('error');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-custom2">Employee Name</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">In Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">Out Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">Unnamed</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="table-custom2">Test User</td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="in-time" class="input-xsmall"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="out-time" class="input-xsmall" onInput="myFunction()"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><span id="value"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good start with what you have done and it works when you fix some of the errors that the others have pointed out `>=` not `=>` but your code right now presumes that they start and finish in the morning or start and finish in the afternoon, if you want to be able to calculate start in the morning and finish in the afternoon you will need to add a bit more.

There are many js plugins that allow you to pick a time, for example https://momentjs.com/ can help you set a time and work out the difference in hours. This can be a good next step in what you are trying to do

You will then be able to do something like this

```
var duration = moment.duration(outTime.diff(inTime));
var workHours = duration.asHours();
```

Then your users will be able to add 8:00am as an in time which you can format

Comment: Thank you for this, I wasn't aware about that plugin. I was actually planning on using 24 hours time format because I couldn't think of a way to use this in 12 hour format. I'll try this plugin now